# As a room owner, starring a message on the transcript marks both pin and star as set, pin doesn't work

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, chat-pins

As a room owner, starring a message on the transcript marks both pin and star as set in the dropdown, and using the pin feature doesn't seem to work.

I for one don't mind if we can't pin on the transcript, and I don't mind if we remove that from the list of choices on the transcript. But it *is* annoying to see both trigger when clicking on star.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your problem.  When you star from the transcript it *says* it pinned it too, but then it's not actually pinned?

Comment: Yes, and the pin icon/action doesn't work.