# Star/unstar/pin/unpin via transcript is broken for room owners

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, chat-pins

This includes [As a room owner, starring a message on the transcript marks both pin and star as set, pin doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170059/as-a-room-owner-starring-a-message-on-the-transcript-marks-both-pin-and-star-as) plus some.

Something is very, very wrong with star/pin/unstar/unpin in the transcript for room owners. At least the following occur, reproducibly, and only through the transcript:

- When RO *stars* message: Message is starred successfully. However, dropdown now incorrectly shows "unpin" as well as correctly showing "unstar". This is the effect reported in the above linked post. Additional detail not mentioned in that link: The dropdown for the message in actual chat or on the starwall still shows "pin" and the message isn't actually pinned, so this is correct at least.
- When RO *unstars* a message: *All existing stars on message are cancelled.* That is, instead of "unstar" happening, it is as if "cancel stars" was selected. This is doubly odd because "cancel stars" isn't actually an available action in the transcript dropdown.

I didn't test pin/unpin, because I already bummed myself out by unintentionally cancelling stars on [a message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3514209#3514209) during testing after I first noticed this, and didn't want to do any further damage. I assume that there is more undiscovered weirdness, though.

The issues *seem* to be primarily related to the dropdown itself in the transcript, although the unintended cancelling of stars is pretty weird.

I believe this is a small step up from a minor issue simply because cancelling stars is irreversible, and an issue that causes irreversible things to happen unintentionally is no good. The star cancelling is primarily why I created a new post for this.

Comment: Could be related to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272383/560648. Probably isn't.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Interesting. At first I thought it was the same but realized you weren't a RO when you observed that. Who knows; something's definitely off with the drop down though.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262220/13